# Can't display selected text in bootstrap-editable using id value while displaying text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

Using bootstrap-editable.js, I have various fields in a table & form all working pretty well, including a few selects.

For one particular select, I want to see the text and save the ID back to the database (whereas, the other selects are just displaying and saving text).

The relevant javascript:

```
    $('#cntryID').editable({
    type: 'select', 
    autotext: 'auto',
    pk: <?php echo($addrID);?>,
    url: '/include/update_address.php',
    // adds a default value if one had already been set
    <?php if ($cntryID<>"") echo("value: $cntryID, \n"); ?>
    source: [<?php 
       // php code that enumerates the values and prints them as below
        echo("\n\t\t" . '{value: "' . $id . '", text: "' .$choice .'"}');
    }
   ?>]
  });
});
```

I've made a jsfiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/pcartagena/qde6k043/

I thought there was an example that demonstrated this very concept but I can't seem to find it to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I'm embarrassed to have to admit that this one took entirely too long to figure out... but...

The problem, as shown in the jsfiddle was that the HTML:

```
    Just the relevent portion shown:
    <a href="#" id="cntryID" data-title="Enter country">228</a>
```

The 228 I putting in between the open/close a tag was throwing it off.  The fact that value was set in the jquery code didn't matter.

I'm posting the answer if only to save someone from wasting as much time as I did on this.   :-)